# Changing format for git branch -vv

Tags: git

I like the -vv format for "git branch -vv" but would like to add "%(committerdate:relative)" to the format and --sort=-committerdate

I've struggled to find the right format from the code (https://github.com/git/git/blob/ccdcbd54c4475c2238b310f7113ab3075b5abc9c/ref-filter.c) but haven't been able to figure it out.

Two questions:
- Does anyone have an alias in their .gitconfig for this?
- Where in the git/git code is -vv implemented?  (https://github.com/git/git)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at the formatting options of [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#_field_names)

A starting point for the format could be :

```
--format='%(refname:short) %(upstream) %(committerdate) %(contents:subject)'
```

You would list references under refs/heads :

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format=...
```

`git for-each-ref` understands `--sort` too

---

[edit] since that answer, I also realized that `git branch` has the same `--format` option :

```
git branch --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream) %(committerdate) %(contents:subject)'
```