# "git branch -vv" change color of remote branches

Tags: git

When calling `git branch -vv` showing the mapping of local to remote branches, the remote branches are colored blue (which is hard to read when working on the command line). How to change the color of the remote branches to e.g. yellow?

I also found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298159/changing-format-for-git-branch-vv) which is unanswered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git config --global color.branch.upstream "yellow"`

From the man page of `git config`:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/#Documentation/git-config.txt-colorbranchltslotgt

> `color.branch.<slot>`
>
> Use customized color for branch coloration. `<slot>` is one of current (the current branch), local (a local branch), remote (a remote-tracking branch in refs/remotes/), upstream (upstream tracking branch), plain (other refs).

You may wish to do the same for `color.branch.remote` (for the output of `git branch -a`, for example.)

Answer (score 6):

You can edit the `.gitconfig` file and write things like this:

```
[color "branch"]
    current = yellow
    local = yellow
    remote = yellow
```

This can be achieved as well with commands like:

```
git config --global color.branch ...
```

For more info on those: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration